# How to have a constant initialization vector and secret key in java?

Tags: java, encryption, dropbox, secret-key

I'm trying to decrypt an `access token` (it's a `String`), which is used to default access an Dropbox account and uploading files into it. So right now, I always need that `access token` to make file uploadings.

Until now, I've been generating a new `initialization vector` (`IV`) and a new `secret key` to encrypt and decrypt the `access token`. However, I want to store these two in the source code, as constant variables/attributes. The reason why I want them to remain the same ? Because I will give a crypted `access token` (always the same encoded one) to the users, and the app should keep the `IV` and the `secret key` inside the source code.

How can I store them in my source code ?

I tried to write the string values of the `IV` and of the `secret key` in files. I use the string from the files, and I assign the string values to string constants in my code. Then i use my constants to create `byte` arrays for converting into the IV and into the secret key. I'm not sure if this will work yet, it's still in development.

Comment: That sounds like a really insecure idea.

Comment: Let me prefix this by saying that is a terrible idea, and you might as well use a different crypto system without an initialization vector. You ***can*** write a program to write arbitrary binary data into source code. Or, read it from a database. Or keep it in a properties file. Still, it's a bad idea to have a constant iv.

Comment: Is there a server-side component to your application? Do you have a user registration process or are they anonymous? Because it would be a lot safer if you can hand out the access token via your server (and not store it in the app or on the client machine), or can even create a separate access token for each user.

Comment: @Thilo : I have no registration process, no server either. Just a desktop local app that should sometimes upload images on dropbox. I'll try some research on creating a separate access token for each user. It sounds like a great idea. I took it for granted that each dropbox account has only one access token.

Comment: If that is the master Dropbox access token, each of these users will then also be able to see each other's uploads? This really does not sound like a good plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd better heed the advice. Storing the key is bad but can sometimes be defended if no other options are available. There is however generally no reason to use a static IV. You can just prefix the IV (which is 16 bytes for most modes of operation) to the ciphertext instead.

Anyway, to store them as static values, just take a look at the following code; note that you should generate them as random values in advance, not the static values you're seeing here:

```
private static final byte[] KEY_DATA = {
    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03,
    (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07,
    (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x0B,
    (byte) 0x0C, (byte) 0x0D, (byte) 0x0E, (byte) 0x0F,
};

private static final byte[] IV_DATA = {
    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03,
    (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07,
    (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x0B,
    (byte) 0x0C, (byte) 0x0D, (byte) 0x0E, (byte) 0x0F,
};

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY_DATA, "aes");
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(IV_DATA);

    aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    ...
}
```

Note that `SecretKeySpec` implements the interface `SecretKey` for easy usage.

Comment: You could of course also take a look at almost each and every bad code sample here on StackOverflow :)